# LTO on Android with clang - is it supposed to work?

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker, clang, lto

I have an NDK project that's compiled by `GCC`. Now I'm trying to compile it with `clang`, and it works, except one thing: as soon as I add `APP_CFLAGS += -flto` (which works with `GCC`), the linker says "invalid character" for each and every `.o` file, and then quits. So, can I enable LTO with clang? If I can, then how?

This is the latest NDK R10e and clang 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and adding

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -flto
```

solved it,

Answer (score 0):

I can uses flto with clang on ndk for armeabi, arme-v7a, x86 and x86_64 but not arm64-v8a...

Comment: Is this really an answer?